# How can I get support for rfc6532 - unicode in address part of email address - in Django 1.5?

Tags: django, unicode, django-forms, django-1.5, django-models

How can I support Unicode in the address part of an email address, under Django?
Django 1.5 rejects these outright:

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> forms.EmailField().clean('pie@obviously.com')
u'pie@obviously.com'
>>> forms.EmailField().clean('◔@obviously.com')
ValidationError: [u'Enter a valid email address.']
```

The document at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6532 is guiding the transition from 7 bit ASCII for the email address to utf-8.  How can I get Django to play along?

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own subclass of `EmailValidator` and you can override the regular expression for `user_regex`. That regular expression is used to validate the user part of an email address. See [`django.core.validators`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py) for the code.

You can then specify that validator for your `EmailField` to ensure the different validator is used.